# SQL pick condition string case by case grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

this is my data where Processname and ProformaInvoiceNum. data is group by progrmainvoicenum.

| ProcessName | ProformaInvoiceNum |
| --- | --- |
| TOP CUTTING | SHE/PBK/23/10001.1 |
| Back Cutting | SHE/PBK/23/10001.1 |
| LINING CUTTING | SHE/PBK/23/10001.1 |
| Cutting | SHE/SHR/22/10155.1 |
| TOP CUTTING | SHE/REHRM/22/10026.4 |
| Cutting | SHE/REHRM/22/10047.4 |
| Recutting | SHE/REHRM/22/10047.4 |
| TOP CUTTING | SHE/SHR/22/10308.1 |
| Cutting | SHE/SHR/22/10308.1 |

i need a new column name of *main process*. if proformainvoicenum have process name 'top cutting' then on that main process feild value show top cutting in that group proformainvoicenum. also if 'top cutting' not exit on that group and 'cutting' is there then 'cutting will be comes on that group profromainvoicenum like below table expample

| ProcessName | ProformaInvoiceNum | Main Process |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TOP CUTTING | SHE/PBK/23/10001.1 | TOP CUTTING |
| Back Cutting | SHE/PBK/23/10001.1 | TOP CUTTING |
| LINING CUTTING | SHE/PBK/23/10001.1 | TOP CUTTING |
| Cutting | SHE/SHR/22/10155.1 | Cutting |
| TOP CUTTING | SHE/REHRM/22/10026.4 | TOP CUTTING |
| Cutting | SHE/REHRM/22/10047.4 | Cutting |
| Recutting | SHE/REHRM/22/10047.4 | Cutting |
| TOP CUTTING | SHE/SHR/22/10308.1 | TOP CUTTING |
| Cutting | SHE/SHR/22/10308.1 | TOP CUTTING |

please help to achived the result

Comment: You could use [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-use-a-select-statement-with-a-simple-case-expression)

Comment: but need this on group by proformainvoicenum

Comment: Use Dependent Sub Query for `Main Process` based on `ProformaInvoiceNum` it will work @AnkurSinghBhandari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a case expression with exists sub-query to check for the required condition

```
select 
case when exists 
          (
              select * 
              from   yourtable x 
              where  x.ProformaInvoiceNum = t.ProformaInvoiceNum
              and    x.ProcessName = 'TOP CUTTING'
          ) 
     then 'TOP CUTTING'  
     when exists 
          (
              select * 
              from   yourtable x 
              where  x.ProformaInvoiceNum = t.ProformaInvoiceNum
              and    x.ProcessName = 'Cutting'
          ) 
     then 'Cutting' 
     else 'Front Cut' 
     end as [Main Process]
from yourtable t
```

Comment: if one more process name we need to group like 'Front Cut'

Comment: What is the condition for `Front Cut`?

Comment: same as cutting if group proformainvoicenum not have top cutting and cutting then consider front cut

Comment: Are there  any more rules or conditions other than these 3 ?

Comment: yes, as front cut

Comment: just add another `when exists` condition to the `CASE` expression

Comment: try but faild please can you help to write